# find the largest consecutive occurrence of the same number in list without import any modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

find the largest consecutive occurrence of the same number in list without import any modules. I have this code

```
def reads():
lst=[] #create empty list

flag=True #create flag
N1=input("Input a number to add to list or 0 to stop: ") #read value
while flag: #check if invalid or not
    
    if not N1.isdigit():
        print("Invalid input")
        N1=input("Input a number to add to list or 0 to stop: ") #re read if invalid
    elif N1=="0": #stop if 0
        flag=False
    else:
        lst.append(N1) #add to empty list if valid
        N1=input("Input a number to add to list or 0 to stop: ") # re read
lst=list(map(int, lst)) #convert to integer
return lst #return

def long(lst):
newx=0 #count
x=lst[0] 
max1=0 #to save the how many number dupilicted
num=lst[0] #to save which number is
for i in range(1,len(lst)):
    if x==lst[i]: 
        
        newx=newx+1
    else:
        newx=newx+1
        if max1<newx:
            max1=newx
            num=x
            x=lst[i]
            newx=0
        else:
            newx=0
            x=lst[i]
return max1,num

def main(): # to call other functions and display the results
x=reads() 
m,a=long(x)
print("List: ",x)
print("The number is: ",a)
print("The largest size of consecutive numbers: ", m)
main()
```

the program run perfectly but there is mistake
if I input `1 1 2 3 4 4 4 0`
the list will be,

```
lst=[1,1,2,3,4,4,4]
```

and output must be

```
The number is: 4
The largest size of consecutive numbers: 3
```

but it be like that:

```
The number is: 1
The largest size of consecutive numbers: 2
```

the problem in long() function

Comment: A tip for the future: use meaningful variable names. E.g: `current_count` is much better name than `newx`. It might not seem important but it lets to reason what your code does and stop errors much more easily.

Comment: Could you reformat the code , some indentation seem odd ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this approach:

```
def long(lst):
    max_count = 1
    max_num = lst[0]
    count = 1
    for prec, num in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:]):
        if num != prec:
            if count > max_count:
                max_count = count:
                max_num = prec
            count = 1
        else:
            count += 1
    return max_num, max_count
```

Comment: Thanks but the mistake still same

Answer (score 0):

`cont_cnt` will continuosly count numbers in the input list, resetting the counter if a number differ from the the previous one. `max_num` then selects the max. The `default=(None, None)` is returned if the list is empty.

```
def cont_cnt(lst):
    prev = object() # guaranteed not to be present in the list
    for x in lst:
        if x != prev:
            count = 0 
            prev = x 
        count += 1
        yield (count, x)

def max_num(lst):
    count, number = max(cont_cnt(lst), default=(None, None))
    print(f"Max: {number=}, {count=}")

max_num([1,1,2,3,4,4,4])
max_num([])
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you check for max number of occurrences only when after changing number (ie when x != lst[i]). As 4 is the last value in the list , it’s count is never tested. You have to move test between max1 and num in the part where you increase num. You also need to increase num only when x equal lst[i] , which imply that count of value should be initiated with 1 :

```
def long(lst):
    newx=1 #count = 1
    x=lst[0] 
    max1=newx #to save the how many number     dupilicted
    num=x #to save which number is
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        if x==lst[i]: 
            # compute new value if consecutive counts
            newx=newx+1
            # check new value of newx 
            if max1<newx:
                max1=newx
                num=x
        else:
            # different values : start new counting
            newx=1
            x=lst[i]

    return max1,num
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the solution, we just need to add fake value into the list and the output will be great !
Below long() function the edit*

```
def reads():
   lst=[] #create empty list

   flag=True #create flag
   N1=input("Input a number to add to list or 0 to stop: ") #read value
   while flag: #check if invalid or not

      if not N1.isdigit():
         print("Invalid input")
         N1=input("Input a number to add to list or 0 to stop: ") #re read if invalid
     elif N1=="0": #stop if 0
         flag=False
     else:
         lst.append(N1) #add to empty list if valid
         N1=input("Input a number to add to list or 0 to stop: ") # re read
  lst=list(map(int, lst)) #convert to integer
  return lst #return

def long(lst):
    lst.append(0) #add fake value to correct the function
    newx=0 #count
    x=lst[0] 
    max1=0 #to save the how many number dupilicted
    num=lst[0] #to save which number is
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
       if x==lst[i]: 
    
          newx=newx+1
       else:
          newx=newx+1
          if max1<newx:
              max1=newx
              num=x
              x=lst[i]
              newx=0
          else:
              newx=0
              x=lst[i]
    return max1,num

def main(): # to call other functions and display the results
    x=reads() 
    print("List:" ,x) #print the list without adding 0 , the fake value****
   m,a=long(x)
    
    print("The number is: ",a)
    print("The largest size of consecutive numbers: ", m)
main()
```